# Grab data from one PHP page and display it on another

Tags: php, session, echo

I do not think that I am doing this the right way, but here goes it. I want to be able to have two php pages `mypage.php` and `mypage2.php`. `mypage2.php` has plain text data on it (say a 8 digit number) and it is just being displayed via the `echo` command.

I want to know if when I am on `mypage.php` if I can grab that number and display it on `mypage.php` rather than open up `mypage2.php` and display it there?

So a hypothetical example of `mypage.php` might be:

```
echo "My secret number is: " . magic_command("mypage2.php");
```

I know that one way to do this is with `$_SESSION`, but doesn't that involve still navigationg to `mypage2.php`, storing the number in `$_SESSION`. Then telling it to go back to `mypage.php`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do:

```
include 'mypage2.php';
```

in `mypage.php` and in `mypage2.php`:

```
echo '12345678';
```

Easy as pie!

Comment: this makes sense and would totally work for the hypothetical problem i gave above unfortunately for my actual issue i cant get it to work. I may not completely understand the `include`. The `mypage2.php` file requires `$_POST` information (i know i totally forgot to add that to the original post. So i don't know if this will still work, but it's closer than i was earlier.

Answer (score 0):

The way you're presenting your question makes me think that you're doing this the hard way. You could store the information in a variable, include the page, and echo it that way. However, I'm assuming there is more to it than that, in which case you're probably looking for a [cURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php), or even a [file_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) solution. Now that I think about it, there are a few ways. Just have to do some research.

Answer (score 0):

If [fopen_wrappers](http://www.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen) are enabled, you can grab the output of one page into another with [readfile()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php), like so:

```
$secret = readfile('http://server/blah/mypage2.php');
echo "My secret number is: $secret";
```

Comment: for some reason when I do this answer it displays the correct info from the `readfile` line and something totally different on the `echo` line.

Answer (score 0):

If that number is user-specific, you should probably store it in a database and then call it when needed.

Otherwise, if you absolutely want to store it in a separate php file, use **include** as yvesonline suggested. **include** acts as if the script in mypage2.php is now inserted into mypage.php.